# Encrypt home drive after installation

Tags: 10.10, encryption, home-directory

I declined to encrypt to my home drive whilst installing ubuntu.

- Is it possible to encrypt it after installation?
- if so, how?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Nanne post](https://askubuntu.com/a/27912/349837) is a quite OLD :

install `sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils`

Read This [How To](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/02/long-overdue-introduction-ecryptfs.html). It's quite easy :

```
sudo ecryptfs-migrate-home -u USER
```

And follow the process. From the link:

> "This will setup the encrypted home directory for the USER and use rsync to do the migration.  **Critically important, USER must login before the next reboot to complete the migration**.  USER's randomly generated mount key is temporarily stored in memory until they login, and eCryptfs picks up the key and encrypts it with their mount passphrase."

Comment: Thanks for the link. im almost tempted just to wait for 11.04 to come out and do it then, ill be doing a fresh install anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably something like this

- make an encrypted filesystem
- move your old ~user
- copy files to encrypted system
- mount encrypted system as ~user

Here's a manual: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemHowto3

Comment: who needs solutions that start with probably?

Comment: people who just need a pointer in the right direction, and can find out stuff for themselves. Also, as not all system information is enclosed, it is impossible to be sure this is what the user needs.