# How to encrypt existing HOME folder on Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, encryption

I am using Kubuntu 20.04 and would like to encrypt the home folder to protect my data if the hard disk / laptop is stolen. Can anybody help me how to do it? Which tool is recommended for it?

Comment: No, it is a default installation. So It is on the same partition as other data. When I create a separate partition for /home how to encrypt it then?

Comment: When I choose a separate partition for home during installation: is there an option to ecrypt only this particular partition? I installed "diska" but the encryption option is greyed out on all partitions.

Comment: But of course I do not like to enter additional passwort for hard disk encryption. I hope it can be encrypter with my Kubuntu user name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

**There is not a guided installation option that will encrypt only your `/home` folder:**

This is likely due to the false sense of security it offers, since your unencrypted OS and swap can expose data kept this way.

**Trying to install Kubuntu 20.04 using "Manual" partitioning to encrypt only `/home` isn't an option either:**

Setting up partitions manually results in a broken installation.  Processes need to access files stored in `~/` immediately after authentication, but it's locked.

---

**There exists a utility to relocate your `/home`: `ecryptfs-utils`:**

It will attempt to migrate your current `/home` to an encrypted location.

Check out hhlp's answer on [Encrypt home drive after installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27911/encrypt-home-drive-after-installation/27918#27918) for more info on using `ecryptfs-utils`.

I have concerns using this method because these kinds of relocations can sometimes be messy, since it's hard to account for all variables.  Also, This utility doesn't seem to address the part of your disk where your `/home` is currently located.  Without securely erasing this data, it could still be recovered without a password.

---

**My suggestion is that you use the guided installation to encrypt Ubuntu entirely**.  This is the only way to ensure that if someone gains physical access to your PC, they won't be able to access data without your decryption key.

Comment: OK, it sounds reasonable. But I would not liuke to enter 2 passwords: one for the HD encryption and one for Kubuntu. Would it be the case then?

Comment: You can check the option to log into your user automatically, and then you only need to enter the decryption key at boot.

Comment: good idea. thx!

Comment: One problem with that is that disk cloning will be slow - determined by the disk/partition size, not by the actually used space.