# How to set user interface language for user with encrypted home?

Tags: encryption, users, home-directory, language-support, ecryptfs

After encrypting home directory by means of [ecryptfs tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27911/encrypt-home-drive-after-installation/27918#27918) specified UI language is not applied after system restart.

If user in the system only one the whole system UI can be changed to needed one. But what to do if there are more than two users and the languages for them must be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuration of UI language for user is stored in `home` directory in file `.pam_environment` (Ubuntu 20.04):

```
LANGUAGE    DEFAULT=en_US:en
LANG    DEFAULT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC  DEFAULT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TIME DEFAULT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY DEFAULT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_PAPER    DEFAULT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NAME DEFAULT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS  DEFAULT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE    DEFAULT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT  DEFAULT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION   DEFAULT=ru_RU.UTF-8
PAPERSIZE   DEFAULT=a4
```

In case of home directory encryption this directory is not available for the system before login - user must enter its password to decrypt this directory. The similar problem with other config files, for example with SSH as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome) in Caveats section.

The solution is to put `.pam_environment` config file in home directory in unmounted state:

- Need to create additional temporary user.
- Reboot the system (to unmount home directory for the current user)
- Login by temporary user and put `.pam_environment` language config file to home directory for needed user.